# Show previous records on Access Form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I think my question may be a little ambiguous - So allow me to explain it.

I'm working on a DB for work that will allow staff to enter support ticket information into a tracker. What I would like is to display the PREVIOUS 5 tickets entered in a sub report / form. But I am having some trouble with displaying results correctly - Is it possible to limit displayed results via VBA?

I have a query set up at that does what I want:

```
SELECT TOP 5 ID, Ticket_Number, Agent, Kickback_Reason, KB_Date, KB_Time
FROM tbl_Tickets
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

It seems things go wrong when I add the query to my form. I think select the master/child fields are messing with the SQL statement - It seems to start listing tickets based on ONE property - I.E shows entries but only date / ticket number - That is to say, the rest of the fields show as empty, as though no data was entered, when the data on the form clearly shows data in other fields for the selected entry.

The only time multiple entries display is if they have the same date / time / Ticket number (dependent on what Master / child field settings are)

I can't think of another way to come at this, either via wizards, manually or via code directly. I would like the sub form / report to display the LATEST 5 entries only and have it update (in real time, is that possible??) the latest entries every time some one clicks the "new record" button.

Hope I've explained this well :/ I've never been great with words. Any help would be appreciated!!

~Matt

Comment: Just like to comment and say - I figured it out, turns out it was the master / child fields causing the issue.
I would like to keep this open for a little longer, see if some one is able to help with making the tickets update in real time / on a timer or potentially provide insight as to a better method to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the "Master" and "Child" fields - I figured this had something to do with why ALL previous 5 entries weren't showing. Thought I may as well try removing those fields, see if that helped - It did.

The query now runs exactly as coded as there are no fields linking the Main form, to the subform - As such, it just displays all results.

I figured this has been open long enough to allow for improved methods of implementing this - and as no one has commented I can only assume there is no better way - Or my description is just poor.

Either way - No point keeping a solved issue open. Thanks any way - and apologies for the waste

~Matt